# Non Json Format to JSON format

Tags: java, regex, json

I have a string which is 'almost' a json string, only that its keys are not surrounded by quotes. 
Normally it is used by the UI and javascript which does not have a problem in interpreting it.  However it seems the JSON parsers in Java that i know of require key to be surrounded by quotes.

Is there a way i can convert the string to a valid json string, probably by using a regular expression in Java.
Or is there a JSON lib which is a bit lenient.

The String will be of the form

```
{
   A : "Val1", 
   B : [ SOME NESTED STUFF], 
   C : "Val3"
}
```

and i need to convert it to

```
{
   "A" : "Val1", 
   "B" : [ SOME NESTED STUFF], 
   "C" : "Val3"
}
```

without affecting any of the nested stuff. The number of keys ie A, B, C is fixed.

Thanks

P.S. I cannot get the appropriate JSON string returned to me, it is a pre existing code and it is quite risky to change it.

Comment: Are Val1 and Val3 guaranteed to contain no double quotes?

Comment: `([^"]\\w+[^"]?):`  ... that's just off the top of my head, but should point you in the right direction. The Idea is to work back from the colon since you know you're looking for one or more word characters that aren't quoted preceding a colon.

Comment: Thank you all...I started using json-smart which is lenient in parsing the json, and does not require the key to have quotes.  http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) it has support for non-standard JSON including unquoted keys: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_310.html

Comment: Thanks....i also realized that Json-smart also has it. http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all line starting with     `unquoted_word :` need the word to be quoted, you could use something like:

```
str.replaceAll("(?m)^(\s+)(\w+)(\s*:)", "$1\"$2\"$3");
```

But if you can you are probably better off using a proper parser like other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

use the following line code to enclose all the keys (single caps letter is considered a valid key here) with double quotes:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\s([A-Z])\s\:\s\"", "\"$1\" : ");
```

Comment: Breaks on `{ A : " B : C "}`.

Comment: if you update like this than it will work s.replaceAll("\\s([A-Z])\\s+([\\:\"])", "\"$1\" $2")

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about the unescaped backslashes.  Even once they're fixed, the expression will still mess up the second a string contains " (some letter) :".

Comment: @cHao: indeed... i did not account for that... i edited my answer to fix this issue by adding the `\"` at the end of the regex string

Comment: @cHao: you can make the regex string much more elaborate to fit all cases, if you would specify the structure of the data you are given it will help generate a more "complete" regex string

Comment: so something like that:) s.replaceAll("([A-Z]){1}\\s?([\\:\"]){1}", "\"$1\" $2")

Comment: @BigFatBaby: A single regex to do the whole job would be enormously complicated, if it's even possible (and i'm gonna guess it's not).  About the only way you could really simplify it is to get a guarantee that certain characters will (only|not) appear in certain places.

Comment: @cHao: so basically you are saying there are no rules to the format of "JSON" data you are recieving? how do you expect to fit it then?

Comment: @BigFatBaby: With proper JSON and a JSON parser, as the gods intended.  Or JS and `eval`.  But either one far exceeds the power of a regular expression.  Regexes are quite limited in their ability; you go that route, before too long you'll be tearing your hair out in frustration.

Comment: @cHao: well... there's that :)... only if the keys being unquoted your only issue with the JSON structure though... if the structure is not consistent then even the gods wont help him there :D

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a regex, this might work:

```
jsonString.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\s*\\:","\"$1\" :");
```

That said, if you are really worried about touching the nested stuff and corner cases, you want a real parser, not a regex.  There's no way that a regex will be precise enough to avoid messing up if one of your values is the string `" A : "`.  If pingw33n is correct about the jackson parser, it is by far the best answer.